# How do I identify which process is creating vitrual interfaces in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, 20.04

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 desktop version and the OS is up to date. I noticed that when I run `ifconfig`, there are about 32 instances of as0t* interfaces like below:

```
as0t0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.224.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.224.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11  bytes 1168 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.224.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.224.129
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11  bytes 1168 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

These interfaces didn't exist before, and I don't know which process is responsible for creating them, or why they even exist in the first place. I know I have vmware installed, but vmware is known to create interfaces going by `vmnet*`.

Running `ip link delete itf_name` deletes the interfaces, but a reboot of the system brings them back.

How do I proceed with this?

Comment: OpenVPN Access Server maybe? See [Why does Access Server have multiple network interfaces?](https://openvpn.net/faq/why-does-access-server-have-multiple-network-interfaces/)